# Auto-naming of Outlook 2010 data files

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm adding a new account to Outlook 2010 on my PC running Windows 7 Professional.  The PC is second-hand, and the previous user did not do a thorough job of removing their personal details.  So when I automatically configure the account settings, Outlook decides to store the data in a data file named according to the previous user (ie, the file name looks like 'my_email_address - prev_user_name.pst').  How can I stop Outlook from naming the data file in this way?

Comment: Delete the Outlook profile.  You can do this by the Mail applet within the Control Panel.  Since you have Outlook 2010 it will be specifically named `Mail (Microsoft Outlook 2010)(32-bit)`.  If you have any of your accounts setup already, backup your data files, before you do this.

Comment: @Ramhound: You should write that as an _answer_, so that it may be _accepted_. Answers do not go in the comments section.